# No module named 'mpd'

Tags: python, mpd

I started a project at school and I have to make an MP3 player using Python and mpd. I tried installing mpd by running:

```
sudo apt-get install mpd
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install mpd mpc
```

in the terminal. I also have

```py
from mpd import MPDClient
client = MPDClient()
```

in Python and gives me the error:

```
ImportError: No module named mpd
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `tried installing mpd using various codes i found on the internet using terminal` ... this is useless information ... you could have said instead "i took my dog for a walk" and it would be the same amount of information ... what did you actually do? .... what were the error messages when you tried?

Comment: click the `edit`  button on your question ... it is right below the `python` `mpd` tags .... add the information about the commands to your question .... list the command line and **any messages that were displayed** .... delete the comment after that .... i will delete this comment and my other comment when you update your question

Comment: @jsotola done:)

Comment: not done :( .... i asked you twice to post the resulting messages when you ran the install commands

Comment: which version of Python are you using 2.x or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mpd](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mpd) is the Music Player Daemon; the actual daemon server that manages playback. [mpc](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mpc) is the command line tool to interface to mpd — but neither of these packages include the bindings to Python.

You need to install these separately:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mpd
```

See the [python-mpd](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-mpd) package listing in the repositories. For Python 3, install `python3-mpd` instead (but this will only work for Raspbian Stretch onwards; no Python 3 bindings are available for Jessie).

Alternatively, you might consider installing from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-mpd2) via Pip, using:

```
sudo pip install python-mpd
```

(`python-mpd2` looks more up-to-date and might be a better choice, though).

I would advise trying the APT method first, and if not, try using Pip.